# Sem with groups

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, group-differences

My purpose is to test the same SEM model on two independent groups. However, some of the variables that participate in the model have significantly different values between the two groups (e.g. age is participate in the model and group1 is significantly older than group2).

Is it still a valid model to consider or I would better use simpler analysis instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem. You allow the means to vary between the groups.

Comment: That was also my view but I was not very confident for that. Thank you for your answer.